# How to get many to many values and store in an array or list in python +django

Tags: python-3.x, django-models

Ok
i have this class in my model :

i want to get the agencys value which is a many to many on this class and store them in a list or array . Agency which store agency_id with the id of my class on a seprate table.

Agency has it's own tabel as well

```
class GPSpecial(BaseModel):
hotel = models.ForeignKey('Hotel')
rooms = models.ManyToManyField('Room')
agencys = models.ManyToManyField('Agency')
```

Comment: Show us your model definitions please (after trimming down the non-relational fields).

Answer (score 2):

You can make it a bit more compact by using the `flat=True` parameter:

```
agencys_spe = list(GPSpecial.objects.values_list('agencys', flat=True))
```

The `list(..)` part is not necessary: without it, you have a `QuerySet` that contains the ids, and the query is postponed. By using `list(..)` we force the data into a list (and the query is executed).

It is possible that multiple `GPSpecial` objects have a common `Agency`, in that case it will be repeated. We can use the `.distinct()` function to prevent that:

```
agencys_spe = list(GPSpecial.objects.values_list('agencys', flat=True).distinct())
```

If you are however interested in the `Agency` objects, for example of `GPSpecial`s that satisfy a certain predicate, you better query the `Agency` objects directly, like for example:

```
agencies = Agency.objects.filter(gpspecial__is_active=True).distinct()
```

will produce all `Agency` objects for which a `GPSpecial` object exists where `is_active` is set to `True`.

Comment: A simple one-liner. One of the best, and living a lonely life :( ?  Better than many accepted solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I think i found the answer to my question:

```
agencys_sp = GPSpecial.objects.filter(agencys=32,is_active=True).values_list('agencys')
agencys_spe = [i[0] for i in agencys_sp]
```